# Multi level virtualisation in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm wondering if there is a concept about virtualisation in multi level structures.

I have a ListView that contains elements that CAN contain another ListView. Out of the box only the toplevel Listview supports virtualisation.

Are there any solutions to get the sublists to virtualize too?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <!-- SubList-->
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you have to limit the Height of every child `ListView`, in the same way the window is limiting the Height of the top level `ListView` making the scrollbar appear. When you limit the Height of child ListViews, you will see an inner scrollbar for each of them if needed, and you can be sure that they are virtualized then.

If this is not acceptable, you will have to build something like a tree-listview

Comment: Thanks. Yes. You are right. But I cannot use this as a solution for my problem.

Comment: @DomenicoThöni, take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control